# The keyboard stops working for a while when logging in windows

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, login

This is a really strange behavior I've been having on my computer for a while (even before my upgrade to windows 10). Here's what happen:

1. Computer boot and when I arrive on the login screen, I enter my credential. Everything works fine so far.
2. When the session loads, all the mouse input works fine (I can click or start any programs without any problems).
3. For about a minutes, it's impossible to use the keyboard. When I type something, it takes like 10-15 sec delay before a character appear in a text input and have to wait another 15 sec for another character to appear.
4. After that lock period, the keyboard works flawlessly.

When I lock it for a while, it does that also when resuming the session.

I've checked the different services at startup but without any success. 
I'm thinking of buying a new keyboard just for testing. Maybe since it's a Microsoft keyboard there is some kind of special initialization? Who knows.

If anyone had encountered a similar issue or have some ideas, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was right. I had one USB component that was plugged in and when I was logging in into windows, for some reason was disabling the keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly a problem with Win 10 drivers with keyboards.  I've done all the troubleshooting suggest by MS (except for going back to Win7) but the problem occurs intermittently.  I figure someone is fixing within MS and it'll be fixed soon.  In the meantime, I can use the mouse to open settings and turn on the on-screen keyboard.  That gets me by 'til I can reboot.

Comment: I'll continue my investigation when I have more time. I had a new idea this morning -> disconnect all USB devices and try if it happens again. I'm thinking maybe another device is overriding the keyboard until it's initialized. Thanks for the OSK suggestion